# Where is java jre path specified in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, java, path, jre

I have java installed including jre 6 and 7 on Windows 7 64-bit.  When I type `java -version` at the command line I get:

```
C:\>java -version
java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

I wanted to make jre7 the default java from the command line so I went to edit my path when I notice java isn't specified anywhere in either System Variables or User Variables (nor is there a JAVA_HOME variable either).  Also running `set` from the command line confirms this as the Path variable has no java directory.  My java is stored in the normal `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6`.

So now I'm curious how is windows finding my current java on the command line?

Comment: it looks like that C:\Windows\System32\java.exe checked first, if you haven't got this file here, java.exe runs from your JDK path

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found a stackoverflow question which has the solution: [JRE installation directory in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930383/jre-installation-directory-in-windows)

Running `where java` gives the output:

```
C:\>where java
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
```

(Didn't realize windows had `where` command just knew it didn't have `which`.) Curious how java.exe ended up there.

**Update**

This oracle article, [Deploying the JRE on Windows](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/runtime-windows-137915.html), states that the Java installer will copy java.exe into the system directory:

> By default, the installer places a copy of the runtime environment in
>   the C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0 directory. In addition, if no more
>   recent version is already installed on the machine, the installer puts
>   copies of the java and javaw application-launcher executables in the
>   Microsoft Windows system directory. (The system directory varies
>   depending on the Microsoft Windows version, but is usually either
>   C:\winnt\system32 or C:\windows\system.)

Answer (score 1):

`C:\Windows\system32\java.exe` is a pretty common location.